# How to reset CSS on a particular hyperlink?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

```css
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 1</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

I have a generic CSS style for hyperlink like:

```
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

but I don't want to apply above css style for one particular hyperlink (link 2) from below code:

```
<div class="nav">
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 1</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Is it possible to handle by having same CSS but to control with some special html property or CSS hack or to write another class style?

Comment: Add a class and target that `a` tag using that classname. or if are worried about that `nav a` use `nth-child` rule and target accordingly

Comment: is there any problem using `classes`

Comment: I added all possible options just using css. See my answer below

Comment: @SagarV I have no problem to use classes or to write extra css but I am looking for efficient solution or css hack to do this.

Comment: But it is a good practise to make use of `class`. For example, if you want to apply one style for 2 links and another style for another 2 links, then it will be difficult without class

Comment: @SagarV, That is also possible using CSS. See my answer

Comment: you used `classes`

Comment: I showed 3 example for parent `div` to show example here. I did not add class to `a` tag. But if you meant parent div then I am agree with you.

Comment: @MubasharIqbal, I know all the answers are correct but you should accept any of them which solved your problem and community. thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found one very simple way to do this:

```
style="all:unset;"
```

we can use this to reset all type of style/css from particular html tags. i.e.

```
<div class="nav">
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 1</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com" style="all:unset;">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Or can create separate class for this reset css. like

```
.reset_particular_tag {
    all:unset;
}

<div class="nav">
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 1</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com" class="reset_particular_tag">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Same thing answered by @yonatan ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42921871/1960558 what is new on your answer?

Comment: I think you didn't get my point and approach, @yonatan approach is totally different from my approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pseudo css properties `last-child`, Also you can use `:nth-child` in many ways: have a look this [https://jsfiddle.net/ruhul105/r5tev6bv/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/r5tev6bv/2/)

```css
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
a:last-child {
  color: red;
}
.nav-one a {
  display: block;
}
.nav-one a:nth-child(1){
  color: green;
}
.nav-one a:nth-child(2){
  color: blue;
}
.nav-two {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.nav-two a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
}
.nav-two a:nth-child(2n){
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 1</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 2</a>
</div>

<h3>Example with nth-child (target by number)</h3>
<div class="nav-one">
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 1</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 2</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 3</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 4</a>
</div>

<h3>Example with nth-child(target only even)</h3>
<div class="nav-two">
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 1</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 2</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 3</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a separate class for that `<a>` tag. Try this :

```
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.mylink {
  color: purple;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 1</a>
   <a href="http://examplelink.com" class="mylink">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

For that particular HTML you can use CSS like that:

```
.nav a:last-child {
    // New CSS Here
}
```

You can also modify the HTML in this way:

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 1</a>
    <a href="http://examplelink.com" class="last-button">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

and then do this CSS:

```
.last-button {
    // New CSS Here
}
```

Or you can change the html to that:

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 1</a>
    <a href="http://examplelink.com" id="my_special_button">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

and then do this CSS:

```
#my_special_button {
    // New CSS Here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a class to the element and then style that class:

```
<div class="nav">
   <a href="http://examplelink.com">Link 1</a>
   <a class="special-link" href="http://examplelink.com">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.special-link {
  color: red;
}
```

Or alternatively, if you want to keep the current html structure:

```
.nav a:nth-child(2) {
 color: red;
}
```

The first method is normally better because it will work even if you add links before/after the link you want to style, and you can also re-use that class to effect other links if you'd want to.